# NLog - combining day and size archiving

Tags: nlog

Using NLog, I want to achieve the following:

- One log file per day.
- Archive on size, unlimited archives.
- Keep max x days of logs, automatically deleting older logs.

How to configure this?

Comment: I'm not sure it's possible to do what you want with NLog. You can use `archiveEvery` for archiving each day, `archiveAboveSize` to limit by size and `maxArchiveFiles` to specify how many archive files to keep.

Answer (score 0):

> - One log file per day.
> - Archive on size, unlimited archives.

This is possible with NLog

Config:

```xml
<target name="file" xsi:type="File"
        layout="${longdate} ${message} ${exception}" 
        fileName="${basedir}/logs/log-${shortdate}.txt" 
        archiveFileName="${basedir}/archives/log.{#####}.txt"
        archiveAboveSize="10240"
        archiveNumbering="Sequence" />
```

> - Keep max x days of logs, automatically deleting older logs

This isn't. You could limit the maximal archives, but not the log files.